# Como passar parâmetro via botão

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Como faço para usar o texto do `@Html.TextBox("pesquisa")` como parametro no código abaixo

```
<button id="BtnConsulta" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Pesquisa", "Cliente", new { PARAMETRO)'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>

</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox("pesquisa")
</div><br />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certifique-se de que seu form esteja usando o método `GET`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Pesquisa", "Cliente", FormMethod.GET)) 
{ 
    <div>
        <button id="BtnConsulta" name="parametro" value="valor" type="submit">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("pesquisa")
    </div>
}
```

Certifique-se também que seu botão tem `name`, `value` e seja do tipo `submit`.

```
        <button id="BtnConsulta" name="parametro" value="valor" type="submit">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </button>
```

O `onclick` não precisa.